# Rails Active Admin Many to Many relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have the following models

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :business_owners
  has_many :businesses, :through => :business_owner
end

class Business < Active Record::Base
  has_many :business_owners
  has_many :businesses, :through => :business_owner
end

class BusinessOwner < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owners
  belongs_to :businesses
end
```

I have attempted to add the BusinessOwner model to the admin dashboard:

```
rails generate active_admin:resource BusinessOwner
```

which creates a file called business_owners in app/admin/
when I attempt to view the Business Owner I receive the following error:

```
uninitialized constant BusinessOwner::Owners
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: render renderer_for(:index)
```

Can someone tell me how to use active admin with many to many relationships?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your relationships don't look right.

On the `belongs_to` relationships, Rails expects you to use the singular form

```
class BusinessOwner < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner
  belongs_to :business
end
```

Likewise, you need to correctly reference the `:through`

```
  has_many :businesses, :through => :business_owners
```

(i.e. plural owners)

It's usually worth firing up the Rails console (OR WRITING TESTS, hehe) to test this stuff before you think about ActiveAdmin ;)

Comment: You rock. My bad on that. Yes a test or two would have caught that.

Answer (score 2):

Correct in bussiness table do association like this:

```
class Business < Active Record::Base
  has_many :business_owners
  has_many :oweners, :through => :business_owner
end
```